# How to Retrieve Multimedia data from Remote server and store document directory using Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jsonp, nsurlconnection, nsdocumentdirectory

Hi every One I am new to iPhone. I am retrieving data from remote server with using nsurlconnection and json parser..I am downloaded only one file from the server and i stored in documents path. But in my server url number of files are there like (images,audios,video,text files). How to download at a time when app lunch and save it in document directory. And also i want the same file name in documents as the file name in the server.

I have tried these way .

```
ViewController 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{

NSMutableData *responseData;

    NSArray *filesCount;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *filesCount;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *responseData;

@end

.m viewController 


#import "ViewController.h"

#import "JSON/JSON.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize filesCount,responseData;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    responseData =[[NSMutableData data]retain];

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXXXXX/XXXXX/filesCount.php"]];

       [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

   [responseData setLength:0];


}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [responseData appendData:data];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"DidFailWithError" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [responseData release];

    NSLog(@"response string is %@",responseString);

    NSError *error;

    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    filesCount = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];

    [responseString release];

    NSLog(@"filesCount is %@",filesCount);

    if (filesCount==nil) {

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Json parsing failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];
    }

    else{

        NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"\n"];

        for (int i = 0; i < [filesCount count]; i++)

            [text appendFormat:@"%@\n", [filesCount objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"text is %s",[text UTF8String]);

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:text ]]];

        NSData *addImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSRange lastComma= [text rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

        NSString *requiredSubString = [text substringFromIndex:(lastComma.location+1)];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:requiredSubString];

        [fileManager createFileAtPath:savedImagePath contents:addImageData attributes:nil];

        NSLog(@"Saved Document dir %@",savedImagePath);

        UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"files are downloaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert1 show];
    }

}
```

Please help me What  wrong i mad.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, I really can't read your question very well.  From what I see though you might benefit from looking at AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).  It simplifies the process of downloading, and is rock-solid.

Look here for a nice tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/

Comment: @.Richard Brown.The Link is good But I need to download the images in Documents folder. want the same file name in documents as the file name in the server. please help me